# Vector data(point) is drawn in wrong place on map (OpenLayers)

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers, point

I need to show a map (world map, used default `OpenLayers` WMS) and one point on it (with events like onhover, etc). Here is my code:

```
                   var options = {
                            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                            maxResolution: 6000
                        };
                        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

                        var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                        "OpenLayers WMS", 
                        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                        {layers: 'basic'}
                    ); 

                    var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");

                    point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(20.088844299316406, 51.8321709083475);
                    vectors.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point)]);

                    map.addLayers([wmsLayer, vectors]);

                    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

But this code locates the point is drawn not in correct place, but somewhere near Africa (that place lat and lon is 0, 0). **Question: Why this happens and can I fix it?** I just need to locate the point to the correct place. Paradox when I print this point in console then it shows that the point lan and lon are as needed (as defined). But it is still in the wrong place...

Answer (score 1):

Your map is in 900913, and point in 4326 projection. You have to transform it from 4326 to 900913:

```
point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(20.088844299316406, 51.8321709083475);
point.transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
);
```

Also, consider centering your map by feature. zoomToMaxExtent() centers map to 0, 0. Since you have set maxResolution to 6000, only small part of map is visible and feature may be out of map bounds.

```
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
map.setCenter([point.x, point.y]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector()` uses `OpenLayers.Geometry` but not an `OpenLayers.Geometry.Point` type. But I never done such kind of app. Just a suggestion which looks reasonable.